# UnitTest++ crashes in iOS project in XCode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, clang, unittest++

I appear to be getting crashes that are not caught by the C++ `try { } catch { }` construct (or which indicate that exception handling itself has become broken) when I include the source for [UnitTest++](http://unittest-cpp.sourceforge.net).

The code compiles fine without any errors, but on runtime I get various crashes.

For example, the `FixturesWithThrowingDtorsAreFailures` built-in test fails with `libc++abi.dylib: terminate called without an active exception`. What I found about this error is that it means something went wrong in the exception handling process.

Is this a peculiarity of the way that Obj-C++ works? Has anyone else tried to get UnitTest++ working?

Comment: I eventually took out 4 tests, and the remaining 173 test test suite passes running on iOS. That's acceptable for me, and having 173 tests that pass is better than nothing.

Comment: Where did you got the sources from? There is a git repository on GitHub here: [unittest-cpp/unittest-cpp](https://github.com/unittest-cpp/unittest-cpp). It contains a Xcode project, and seems to be actively developed.

Comment: Interesting! I didn't find this one. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Same issue, here: https://github.com/unittest-cpp/unittest-cpp/issues/45

Looks like this project has "fresher" code though, and once I cut out the failing bits, there are 228 tests in the suite. So I might bring it into my project.